# NoReverseMatch at all locations, Django 1.9

Tags: django

So I'm making a web app in Django with a friend, using Django 1.9. However, recently I pulled some minor changes from our git repo and all of a sudden I get NoReverseMatch regardless of where I try to go on our page. It works fine for my friend, and we are using the same version of Django.

The changes made were in forms.py and views.py, with nothing having been touched in urls.py, where I gather the most common cause of this problem comes from.

We have two urls.py files, one in our app directory:

```
(imports and fluff omitted)
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', views.index, name = 'index'),
url(r'^play', views.play, name='play'),
url(r'^create_user/$', views.create_user, name='create_user'),
]
```

and one in the directory above the app dir:

```
(imports and fluff omitted again)
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('antonymapp.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/login/$', login),
]
```

The problem does remain regardless of where the url is defined.

This is our views.py file, with imports omitted:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'antonymapp/index.html', {})


def login(request):
    return render(request, 'antonymapp/login.html', {})

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        return redirect('play')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

return render(request, 'antonymapp/create_user.html', {'form': form}) 

@login_required
@csrf_protect
def play(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid()) 
        if form.is_valid():
            picked = form.cleaned_data.get('picked')
            picked = int(picked[0])
            player = request.user.userprofile
            player.score = player.score + picked
            player.save()
    else:
        form = SomeForm

    return render(request, 'antonymapp/play.html', {'form':form })
```

**Big edit with info**
The stacktrace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['antonyms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'antonymapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/antonymapp/templates/antonymapp/index.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []   1 : {% extends 'antonymapp/base.html' %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 :  <h1> Hej och välkommen till vår sida! </h1>
   5 :  <p>
   6 :      <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">Logga in</a>
   7 :  </p>
   8 :  <p>
   9 :      <a href="{% url 'create_user' %}" class="user-text">Skapa användare</a>
   10 :     </p>


Traceback:

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                               current_app=current_app)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'antonyms.post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []), another exception occurred:

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/antonymapp/views.py" in index
  15.   return render(request, 'antonymapp/index.html', {})

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  326.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  955.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  513.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  686.         raise value

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  499.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/home/lisa/Documents/Skola/Kex/AntonymApp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'post_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

forms.py
from django import forms

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = ((1,'1'),
               (2,'2'),
               (3,'3'),
               (4,'4'),
               (5,'5'),)
    picked = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Me and my friend are sitting on separate computers, we had both fixed a bug (in the same way) he pushed the changed to github. I then deleted the changes I'd made and pulled down his changes (we haven't learned how to handle branches in github yet).

So I'm not sure i I can find the diff since I never committed my files before deleting my changes and pulling down his changes.

**EDIT**

What I ended up doing was deleting my local version of the project and then cloning from git. It works now, but I have no idea why and what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the `NoReverseMatch` error. What changes have you made to `forms.py` and `views.py`? There could be a syntax error which means that the imports fail. It will be easier to spot this by looking at the diff.

Comment: `url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),`

Comment: It appears django is unable to find url named `post_new`...do you have it as an entry in your urlpatterns?

Comment: There is a post_new url in an app in another project (separated by directories and virtual envirnonments.... and I've made sure I'm running the server in the correct project). By the way, my friend Finbel and I both appreciate the help yesterday :)

Comment: Maybe you mistakenly used `post_new` url name in a template. Glad to know that I was any help for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the corpus, I just had this happen also. It's a pretty basic project with nothing that interesting going on.

All I had changed was installing `psycopg2` and a project that was working ceased working with the same error as described above.

Though rather than deleting my project I uninstalled and the reinstalled *django* in the environment and suddenly the urls were working again.

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Django 2.1.1
```

Yay, weird bugs.